# Ruby FTP server "halts"

Tags: ruby, sockets, ftp

I am trying to implement the FTP protocol in Ruby. The problem is that when the user enters the `bye` command my program doesn't respond (the other commands work fine). Here is some of my code (the socket parts are omitted). Can anyone tell me what is going wrong? (I know that when `bye` is entered the standard windows FTP program sends "QUIT".)

```
user_on = true

while user_on  
  cmd = client.recv(2000)

  # THIS IS WHERE IT FREEZES
  if cmd.contains? 'QUIT'
    client.puts("221 Goodbye.")
    client.close
    user_on = false
  else
    puts("500 UNRECOGNIZED COMMAND")
    cmd = client.recv(2000)
  end

end
```

Comment: I think nobody can solve this problem without implementation details. But maybe you should check whether cmd really contains 'QUIT'.

Comment: Did you flush? I'm not sure if that is needed, but worth a try.